# How to subtract dateTimePicker fields in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I have 2 dateTimePicker fields on my form.

How can I subtract those fields?

For example if I have field1 = Friday/May/1 and field2 = Sunday/May/3
I want to get subtract value in textBox field3 = field2 - field1 = 3 (friday, saturday, sunday)

Comment: What is the subtracted value supposed to represent?  The number of days between the two dates?

Comment: @Francine yes, if fromdate is today and toDate is sunday then it should give value 3. 
3 because today, tomorrow and after tomorrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
DateTimePicker d1;
DateTimePicker d2;

public void ComputeDifference()
{
    TimeSpan diff = d2.Value - d1.Value;
    int days = diff.Days + 1;
}
```

You have to add one as the difference between 5/1 and 5/3 is actually 2.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
DateTime field1 = new DateTime(2015, 5, 1);
DateTime field2 = new DateTime(2015, 5, 3);
TimeSpan difference = field2 - field1; 

Console.WriteLine("Difference in days: " + difference.Days);
```

Comment: Can I pass my dateTimePicker field value instead of direct (2015, 5, 1) ?

Comment: @AYETY Yes, `DateTimePicker.Value` is a `DateTime` so it will work.